# Area in d dimensions of a spherical part

Tags: geometry, area

Let $S^{d-1}$ be the unit sphere (centered at $O$) in $d$ dimensions. One can show that when $d=3$, for fixed $x\in S^{2}$ the area of $P(x) = \{y\in S^{2}, \angle xOy < \alpha \}$ is $2\pi(1-\cos\alpha)$. What is the analogous result in $d$ dimensions?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Here's an approach using the incomplete beta function: https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=ajms.2011.66.70

Comment: It looks like this was answered before (with the incomplete beta function) in an answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238156/what-is-the-surface-area-of-a-cap-on-a-hypersphere, which (except for minor differences in notation) seems completely equivalent to this question.