# Average chord length on a unit $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere in $n$-dimensional space

Tags: probability, geometry, spheres

How to find the average chord length on a sphere of radius $1$? It is clear that this cannot be done as long as there is no law of distribution of its endpoints. Two probability distributions seem logical:

1. Two points uniformly distributed on the sphere are taken and connected by a segment;
2. A random direction is taken and parallel to it, uniformly along the projection of the sphere onto a plane perpendicular to this direction, a segment inside the ball is taken.

It turns out that these are completely different models!

In model 1), the average chord length for all $n$ is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$, since the second point with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ is in another hemisphere and the distance in this case is greater than $1$. In model 2), the average chord length tends to zero! Since it is equal to the volume of the $n$-dimensional ball divided by the volume of the $(n-1)$-dimensional ball.

Such nonsense happens in the $n$-dimensional case, I want to figure it out! And how to calculate exactly the average chord length in 1) case?

Comment: For high dimensions, under the first method the vectors from the center to the two random points will probably be close to orthogonal and the chord length will probably be about $\sqrt2.$ See [Probability of two random points being orthogonal in higher-dimensional unit sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3059747/139123).

Comment: Even in 2D, there are ambiguity issues. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find the average in case 1) by using [polar coordinates in $n$ dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates). As endpoints of the chord we can take
$$
\begin{align}
&P=(1,0,\dots,0),\\
&Q=(\cos\phi_1,
\sin\phi_1\cos\phi_2,\dots,
\sin\phi_1\cdots\sin\phi_{n-2}\cos\phi_{n-1},
\sin\phi_1\cdots\sin\phi_{n-2}\sin\phi_{n-1}),
\end{align}
$$
so that:
$$
PQ^2=(1-\cos\phi_1)^2+\sin^2\phi_1=2(1-\cos\phi_1).
$$
We can then [integrate that over the whole sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Direct_integration_in_spherical_coordinates) to get the average value of $PQ$:
$$
\langle PQ\rangle={
\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\cdots\int_0^{2\pi}
\sqrt{2(1-\cos\phi_1)}
\sin^{n-2}\phi_1\sin^{n-3}\phi_2\cdots
\sin\phi_{n-2}\,d\phi_1\,d\phi_2\cdots d\phi_{n-1}
\over
\int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\cdots\int_0^{2\pi}
\sin^{n-2}\phi_1\sin^{n-3}\phi_2\cdots
\sin\phi_{n-2}\,d\phi_1\,d\phi_2\cdots d\phi_{n-1}
}.
$$
Note that all integrals factor out, with the exception of that in $\phi_1$:
$$
\langle PQ\rangle={
\int_0^\pi
\sqrt{2(1-\cos\phi_1)}
\sin^{n-2}\phi_1\,d\phi_1
\over
\int_0^\pi
\sin^{n-2}\phi_1\,d\phi_1
}
=\frac{2^{n-1} \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\right)^2}
{\sqrt{\pi }\,\Gamma\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}.
$$

Comment: Point $Q$, in my opinion, is not uniformly distributed on the sphere, if the $\phi$ are evenly distributed over the parallelepiped. Consider the case of an ordinary sphere in three-dimensional space. The answer is $\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: @Cornifer And in fact, plugging $n=3$ in my formula you get $4/3$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I jumped to conclusions! :)

Comment: If $Q$ weren't uniformly distributed on the sphere you couldn't use the integral at denominator to compute the area of the spherical surface.

Comment: Yup, everything is fine. I even calculated the limit. As $n$ tends to infinity $\sqrt{2}$. But in your integrals, the last integrand factor seems to be $\sin \varphi_{n-2}$. I also have a question about $n=1$. What's the point of chord length in this case?

Comment: You are right about $\sin\phi_{n-2}$, I corrected the typo. For the limit $\sqrt2$ see the comment by David K above. For $n=1$ the integrals are meaningless, I think.

Comment: In case 2) the chord length is obtained by dividing the volume of an $n$-dimensional ball by the volume of an $(n-1)$-dimensional ball, i.e. $\frac{\Gamma(n / 2+1 / 2)}{\Gamma(n / 2+1)} \sqrt{\pi}$ and this tends to zero.