# A direction that is far from any n directions of the vertices of a hypercube

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry

$C_n \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \left\{\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right\}^n$

**Question**:
Is the following true?

For all $K>0$, $n$ large enough and $r_1,..,r_n \in C_n$, there exists a unit vector $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|c\cdot r_i| \leq \frac{1}{K\sqrt{n}}$ for all $i \in [n]$.

**Discussion**:
Since any $(n-1)$-subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a spanning set, it can be shown that:

For any $r_1,..,r_{n-1} \in C_n$, there exists a unit vector $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|c\cdot r_i| = 0 \left( \text{hence }\leq \frac{1}{K\sqrt{n}} \right)$ for all $i \in [n-1]$.

For the $n$-subsets of $C_n$ that I checked manually (and with Mathematica), the conjecture is true.

Comment: Have you tried a volume argument? Each point  knocks out a certain amount of surface area of the hyper sphere which, I think for big $n$ might approach 0 fast enough.

Comment: @AnneBauval, the problem is for $n$ "large enough", as mentioned in the statement. That is, for all $K>0$, there exists and $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, [conjecture statement].

Comment: @Eric, each pair of caps that is knocked out by a single $r \in C_n$ contains a constant fraction of the volume of the sphere. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4688054/948760) answer for an "empirical proof" for this.
Hence, the approach you suggested will not work.

Comment: Check Khintchine inequality in Wkipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false if $K>1$ and $n$ is a power of 2.

This is true for $K=1$ for all $n$.

Let’s give the counterexample when $K>1$ and $n$ is a power of 2 first.

When n is a power of 2, you can use the columns of the Hadamard matrix of size $n$ to get $n$ orthogonal vectors from within $C_n$.

Since the vectors $r_i$ form an orthogonal basis and $c$ is a unit vector, we have that:

$1=\sum_i |c \cdot r_i|^2$

Since the average value of $|c_i \cdot r_i|^2$ is $1/n$, at least one component must be at least as much, so there is no vector $c$ all of whom’s components $|c \cdot r_i|$ are less than $1/\sqrt{n}$.

—————-

If we fix $K=1$, then such a $c$ always exists.

Given some $r_i$, let’s show it. Note that if the $r_i$ are linearly dependent, we can just choose an orthogonal vector, so let’s assume they’re independent.

If you think of the $r_i$ as a basis and $R$ as the corresponding matrix, then $C:=R^{-1}$ gives the n $c_i$ vectors for which $r_i \cdot c_j=\delta_{i,j}$. Since the $r_i$ are unit vectors, $|c_i| \geq c_i\cdot r_i / |r_i| =1$.

Let’s loop through the list adding or subtract $c_i$ depending on whether $c_i$ has a positive dot product with the sum so far. Precisely, let $s_0$ be the zero vector. Let $f$ be the sign function (negative to -1, positive to 1, and let use 1 to break ties at 0). Then, for $i\geq 0$, let $s_{i+1}=s_{i}+f(s_i \cdot c_{i+1})c_{i+1}$.

Then by induction we have that $|s_i|^2 \geq i$ since $|s_0|=0$ and $|s_{i+1}|^2=|s_{i}|^2+2f(s_i \cdot c_{i+1})s_i \cdot c_{i+1} + |c_{i+1}|^2 \geq i +0+1$.

Also, as the sum or difference of all the $c_i$ we have that $s\cdot r_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n} f(s_{j-1}\cdot c_j)c_j \cdot r_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n} f(s_{j-1}\cdot c_j)\delta_{i,j}= f(s_{i-1} \cdot c_i)=\pm 1$.

Normalizing $s$ gives a vector with all the desired properties. It would be a unit vector for with $|(s/|s|) \cdot r_i|=1/|s| \leq 1/\sqrt{n}$ for all $i$ as desired.